# How to set GridLayout cols to different widths

Tags: html, css, nativescript

I am trying to make a GridLayout with a label and 5 images. The 5 images should have (approx) the same size as the label. My code (currently):

```
        <GridLayout columns="*,*,*,*,*,*" rows="*,*">
            <Label col="0" row="0" class="segment-rating-label" [text]="'RATING_AVG'|translate">
            </Label>
            <!-- The images are starting here -->
                    <Image src="{{ avg_rating_imageurls[0] }}" col="1" row="0" class="star-image" (onTap)="logTap()">
                    </Image>
                    <Image src="{{ avg_rating_imageurls[1] }}" col="2" row="0" class="star-image">
                    </Image>
                    <Image src="{{ avg_rating_imageurls[2] }}" col="3" row="0" class="star-image">
                    </Image>
                    <Image src="{{ avg_rating_imageurls[3] }}" col="4" row="0" class="star-image">
                    </Image>
                    <Image src="{{ avg_rating_imageurls[4] }}" col="5" row="0" class="star-image">
                    </Image>
            <!-- and end here -->
            <Label col="0" row="1" class="text-details segment-content" [text]="'RATING_USER'|translate">
            </Label>
            <!-- and here is another stack of images -->
                    <Image src="{{ user_rating_imageurls[0] }}" col="1" row="1" class="star-image" (onTap)="rateFromUser('1')">
                    </Image>
                    <Image src="{{ user_rating_imageurls[1] }}" col="2" row="1" class="star-image" (onTap)="rateFromUser('2')">
                    </Image>
                    <Image src="{{ user_rating_imageurls[2] }}" col="3" row="1" class="star-image" (onTap)="rateFromUser('3')">
                    </Image>
                    <Image src="{{ user_rating_imageurls[3] }}" col="4" row="1" class="star-image" (onTap)="rateFromUser('4')">
                    </Image>
                    <Image src="{{ user_rating_imageurls[4] }}" col="5" row="1" class="star-image" (onTap)="rateFromUser('5')">
                    </Image>
            <!-- ending here -->
        </GridLayout>
```

My css classes for these:

```
.star-image {
    width: 20;
    margin: 10;
}

.segment-rating-label {
    min-width: 100;
    margin-left: 10;
    margin-right: 20;
}
```

Sadly the GridLayout has for every column the same size. How can I influence these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `*,*,*,*,*,*` to `*5,*,*,*,*,*` and see the magic happen!

Those stars have a relative size, compared to other stars - so *5 means "take up 5 times the space of a regular *".